# How do I use a charge density to calculate an electric field (e.g. $\nabla \cdot\vec E = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$)?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

Simple, possibly stupid question, but here it is.

So I know $$\nabla \cdot\vec E = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0},$$ but how do I use a given charge density to calculate an electric field?

I guess the root of my question is about the mathematical procedure of "undoing" the div operator.

Comment: The div operator represents differentiation. Do you know how to solve differential equations?

Comment: Yeah, so would I just differentiate the charge density expression?

Comment: No - you have to integrate both sides to get E on the left. See [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33847/26969) and associated answer - which is probably a duplicate of this one...

Comment: You also need the curl of the $\vec{E}$ field.  If this is electrostatics ($\nabla X\vec{E}=0$), then you can just use Coulomb's law for a continuous charge distribution: $\vec{E}=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int \frac{dq}{r^2}\hat{r}$

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, @Floris. The other question is about electric potential, this is about electric field. It's trivial to get from potential to field (negative gradient), but they are distinct concepts. In Purcell's textbook they draw a triangle among charge density, electric field, and electric potential, with lines going both directions between every pair of quantities with formulae for how to get from one to the other.